# Global variable as a namespace? Defining ambient typescript definitions for StarUML

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings, staruml, ambient

I'm trying to define the TypeScript type definitions for the [StarUML tool](https://staruml.io/). I've managed to make it work for a good part of the API but I'm getting stuck on the following problem: how to make the link between a (JavaScript) global variable ("type" below) and a TypeScript namespace containing classes?

## (A) The problem to solve

StarUML makes available a global variable `type` that register hundreds of class coming from unknown places. For instance `type.Element` is a class (not an Element!) as well as `type.Model`. We use these two types as an example below:

- In JavaScript, these classes are mostly used in statements like `if (x instanceof type.Element)`.
- With TypeScript, I want to be able to define signatures like `f(e : type.Element)` (I would be happy to remove the type prefix but that's another story) and want to have intelli-sense for expressions like `myElement._id` (`_id` is an attribute of the class `Element`).

## (B) First attempt: modeling "type" as a variable

I first tried to define type as being a variable (as this is actually a
variable):

```
// type.d.ts

declare class Element {
    _id: string
    // ...
}
declare class Model extends Element {
    name: string
    // ...
}

declare const type = {
    "Element" = Element,
    "Model" = Model
    // ...
}
```

This does not work, as it produces the following error:

> S1254: A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference

I mention this solution because it makes it clear what `type` is all about: a register that gives for each class name (string), and the class itself. The classes are defined somewhere else in an unknown place.

## (C) Second attempt: modeling "type" as a Namespace.

After reading the TypeScript documentation, and after various trials, I came up with the following TypeScript file `types.d.ts` (That might be where I'm wrong).

```
// types.ts
export namespace type {
    class Element {
        _id: string
        // ...
    }
    class Model extends Element {
        name: string
    }
    // ...
}
```

## (D) Client code

Below is an example code (`main.ts`) that uses this API definition.
To simplify the file `type.d.ts` and `main.ts` are at both at the top level.

```
// (1)     /// <reference path="./types.d.ts" />
// (2)     import {type} from "./types"
// (3)     declare var type

function hello(m: type.Element): void {
    console.log("    hello: (" + e._id + ')')
}
console.log(type)
console.log(type.Element)
```

I don't manage to "make it work" I've tried various combinations
uncommenting some of the first 3 lines (see below).

#### (D.2) My expectations

- (a) the type in the `function hello` should be defined properly (TypeScript)
- (b) the intelli sense should work on the next line `e._id` (TypeScript)
- (c) the last line should display the `type.Element` class (JavaScript)

I can't make it work all at the same time, irrespective of the "importing"
first lines.

#### (D.3) What I got

- (1) I didn't manage to make line (1) `/// <reference ...` "work" at all. I also tried solutions provided in forums such as using `tsconfig` with `typeRoots` and `paths`. I don't know if the solution should come from there.
- (2) `import {type} ...` is ok for the namespace but then line  `console.log(type.element)` return undefined at runtime.
- (3) `declare var type` makes the JavaScript code run ok, but in conflict with (2).

When (2) and (3) are present at the same time, a TypeScript error is generated because of conflict between `type` as namespace and `type` as variable.

#### (D.4) What is the solution?

After reading the TypeScript documentation and some other blogs I'm still confused. I don't know if the problem is in my approach (C), "modeling the variable type" as a namespace, or I don't know how to call this namespace/variable at compilation/runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm only middling-good at TypeScript, and less so with regard to `.d.ts` files. But this worked locally and seems to match up with [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html), in particular [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#objects-with-properties).

A `.d.ts` file defines ambient declarations, you don't use `export` in it (as far as I know), you just declare things in it, since the purpose is to declare things that *already* exist (in your case, because of the SmartUML library creating that `type` global and its properties at runtime).

So in your `.d.ts` file, you *declare* a namespace containing those classes:

```typescript
/**
 * SmartUML namespace global.
 */
declare namespace type {
    /**
     * SmartUML `Element` class.
     */
    class Element {
        /**
         * The ID fo the element.
         */
        _id: string;
        // ...
    }
    /**
     * SmartUML `Model` class.
     */
    class Model extends Element {
        /**
         * The name of the model.
         */
        name: string;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much ! This is what I needed. No everything is fine. I had also issues with my but now thanks to your explanationI much better understand how it works. Thanks !